# Formatter error of WCF webservice while consuming through soap UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, exception, soapui

I am consuming `https` wcf service ,where for an input string `useremail`,if i put valid strings or emails , no issues.But if i put `<test>test(1)</test>`.Through soap UI i am getting a big error like "`The formatter through an exception while trying to deserializ....End element 'useremail' from namespace'' expected"`,where in visual studio charcters `<` and `>` will be converted to `lt` and `gt`.Our security team is checking webservice through soap ui and doesnot want this big error message in Soap UI.So i am thinking a way to catch these exception through code and display a generic simple message. One additional thing i did in code is i am validating '`useremail`'  as valid email or not.But when triggering through soap UI, it is not at all reaching that validation rather giving a big errors.

I did following snippet code,but this is not at all reaching on the code

```
try
        {
          bool isvalid =ValdiateXMl(request.email);
    if(!isvalid)
{
    "invalid email"
}

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            log.Info(ex.Message);
            response.ErrorCode = -1;
        }
        finally
        {
                      log.Info("invalid email"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the problem is not with SoapUI. It is the "illegal characters" that should be properly substituted with their respective XML character references.

< and > needs to be converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

But I would expect the XML parser to handle that for you.

Comment: How to create an xml parser here.because nothing is reaching in code if they insert through soap ui

Comment: Are you saying someone is adding < and > in the request, and THAT is the problem?

Comment: yes our testers are doing some tests and and they are using soap UI for this.is there any way can tackle this in code.When i tested through Visual studio client application .It works fine

Comment: The solution could be found in SoapUI document [https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html),you could also use  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() method to encode your xml string.

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt. But if your testers are doing that, then they are stupid. They are modifying the XML, so that it no longer complies with the contract. That is destined to fail. If they try something similar through a UI, and that is transformed into XML, I would expect those characters to be either properly encoded or - as you linked - wrapped in CDATA. EDIT: That came out harsh. But they should be told that doing that is not a proper test. If they wish to see how you handle tags, they may do that, but this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @ Ackelry Xu yours is the answer